# How can I check a Pandas DataFrame's column against itself?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I have a Pandas DataFrame with two relevant columns. I need to check column A (a list of names) against itself, and if two (or more) values are similar enough to each other, I sum the values in column B for those rows.
To check similarity, I'm using the FuzzyWuzzy package that accepts two strings and returns a score.

Data:

```
a            b   
apple        3 
orang        4 
aple         1  
orange       10  
banana       5
```

I want to be left with:

```
a       b
apple   4
orang   14
banana  5
```

I have tried the following line, but I keep getting a KeyError

```
    df['b']=df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[fuzz.ratio(df.a,x.a)>=70,'b'].sum(), axis=1)
```

I would also need to remove all rows where column b was added into another row.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some parts here are best done with pandas, and some parts (e.g., a function applied to a cartesian product) can be done without it.

Overall, you can do this with:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

alias = {l : r for l, r in itertools.product(df.a, df.a) if l < r and 
fuzz.ratio(l, r) > 70}
>>> df.b.groupby(df.a.replace(alias)).sum()
apple      4
banana     5
orange    14
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

---

The line

```
alias = {l : r for l, r in itertools.product(df.a, df.a) if l < r and 
fuzz.ratio(l, r) > 70}
```

creates a map `alias`, mapping words to their alias from `a`.

The line

```
df.b.groupby(df.a.replace(alias)).sum()
```

groups `b` by a translation using `alias`, and then sums.

Comment: Amazing! This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would map and groupby:

```
def get_similarity(df, ind, col):
    mapped = list(map(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x, df[col].loc[ind]), df[col]))
    cond = (np.array(mapped) >= 70)
    label = df[col][cond].iloc[0]

    return label
```

And use like this:

```
df.groupby(lambda x: get_similarity(df, x, 'a'))['b'].sum()
```